# Can i send multiple values into this web service request

Tags: php, web-services, soap

here is the WSDL http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL

I'm trying to get more than 1 stock in response. Is it possible in this web service?
The web service requires 1 parameter, which is Symbol. So my code for inserting 1 symbol is

> $wsdl =
>   "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL";
>   // the wsdl
>   $client = new
>   SoapClient($wsdl);
>   $quote =
>   $client->GetQuote((object)array('symbol'=>'SPY'));
>   var_dump($quote);
>   echo $quote->GetQuoteResult . `"<br />"`;

I get the following response which is correct

> `<StockQuotes><Stock><Symbol>SPY</Symbol><Last>133.51</Last><Date>5/27/2011</Date><Time>4:00pm</Time><Change>+0.51</Change><Open>133.37</Open><High>133.87</High><Low>132.9588</Low><Volume>120921856</Volume><MktCap>N/A</MktCap><PreviousClose>133.00</PreviousClose><PercentageChange>+0.38%</PercentageChange><AnnRange>101.13
>   - 137.18</AnnRange><Earns>0.00</Earns><P-E>N/A</P-E><Name>SPDR
>   S&P
>   500</Name></Stock></StockQuotes><br />`

How could i get for example the info of 3 tickers in a single request? For example the tickers are SPY, ^NZ50 and QQQ? I have tried different solutions, for example `$quote = $client->GetQuote((object)array('symbol'=>'^NZ50', 'symbol'=>'QQQ', 'symbol'=>'SPY'));`
I get same XML with last element - SPY ticker info.
With this one `$quote = $client->GetQuote((object)array('symbol'=>'^NZ50','QQQ','SPY'));` i get only first ticker NZ50.

Is it even possible in this web service get response with more than 1 tickers info? How should i forge the input?

Here is the `GetQuoteSoapIn` element

> `<s:element name="GetQuote">
>
>   <s:complexType> <s:sequence>
>
>   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
>   name="symbol" type="s:string"/>
>
>   </s:sequence>
>
>   </s:complexType>
>
>   </s:element>`

And `GetQuoteHttpGetIn`

> `<wsdl:message name="GetQuoteHttpGetIn">
>
>   <wsdl:partname="symbol" type="s:string"/>
>
>   </wsdl:message>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
array('symbol'=>'^NZ50, QQQ, SPY')
```

Based on the usage [here](http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote) if you enter `^NZ50, QQQ, SPY` (separated by commas with spaces - not `^NZ50,QQQ,SPY`) it returns an XML response with the `<symbol>` data for the 3.